# Popup menu for JButton (used in JTable)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableButtonCell extends JFrame {
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;

    public TableButtonCell() {
        setTitle("JButton in JTable");
        setSize(300,150);
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        String [] columns = new String[] {"Text", "Button"};

        String[][] data = new String[][]{
                            {"Line 1", ""},
                            {"Line 2", ""},
                            {"Line 3", ""}};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);
        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
        table.getColumn("Button").setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {
        public ButtonRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText((value == null) ? "Modify" : value.toString());
            return this;
        }
    }

    class ButtonEditor extends JButton implements TableCellEditor {
        public ButtonEditor() {
            JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();

            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Menu action 1");
            item.addActionListener(this::menuAction);

            item = new JMenuItem("Menu action 2");
            item.addActionListener(this::menuAction);

            setComponentPopupMenu(popup);

            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"JButton clicked");
                }
            });
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)  {            
            return this;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue()  {
            return null;
        }

        public void menuAction(ActionEvent ev) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"JButton clicked");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelCellEditing() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        }

        @Override
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TableButtonCell f = new TableButtonCell();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The SSCE above creates a JTable with JButton as cell renderer/editor.
It's working fine & button action is triggered correclty

When trying to add a popup menu to the JButton, the menu is not shown when clicking mouse right button.

Looks like the table is consuming the Mouse right click event, so the JButton didn't receive & react to the event ?

Any clue ?

Thanks in advance for any guidance/help

Comment: The MoueListener needs to be added to the `JTable`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743427/jtable-right-click-popup-menu/16744590#16744590 for a basic example. You would customize the logic to only show the popup when the mouse is clicked in the proper column.

Comment: Adding MouseListener to the JTable does not change anything. I mean the listener is called but e.isPopupTrigger() returns always false. The exemple you gave is not working (no popup menu is shown)

Answer (score 1):

Now it's working with the following code. Hope this may help some one else.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableButtonCell extends JFrame {
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JTable table;

    public TableButtonCell() {
        setTitle("JButton in JTable");
        setSize(300,150);
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        String [] columns = new String[] {"Text", "Button"};

        String[][] data = new String[][]{
            {"Line 1", "Button 1"},
            {"Line 2", "Button 2"},
            {"Line 3", "Button 3"},
            {"Line 4", "Button 4"}};

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columns);
            table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(model);

            ButtonRendererEditor renderer = new ButtonRendererEditor(table, 1);
            TableColumn tc = table.getColumn("Button");
            tc.setCellRenderer(renderer);
            tc.setCellEditor(renderer);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class ButtonRendererEditor extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {
        int column;

        public ButtonRendererEditor(JTable table, int column) {
            this.column = column;

            JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Menu action 1");
            item.addActionListener(this::menuAction);
            popup.add(item);

            item = new JMenuItem("Menu action 2");
            item.addActionListener(this::menuAction);
            popup.add(item);

            addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"JButton clicked");
                }
            });

            table.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                     if (!e.isPopupTrigger())
                         return;

                     JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
                     int col = source.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                     if (col != column)
                         return;

                     popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            });
        }

        public void menuAction(ActionEvent ev) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Menu item clicked");
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            return this;
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)  {            
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            return this;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue()  {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelCellEditing() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {           
        }

        @Override
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TableButtonCell f = new TableButtonCell();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is this code different than the code provided in link? If e.isPopupTrigger always returns false, then the above code should always exit from the mouseReleased event?

Comment: I simply tried both codes