# JPopupMenu only for entries of JList, not all space of the JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jpopupmenu

I want to display a `JPopupMenu` on right click on elements of a `JList`.

`jList.setComponentPopupMenu(...)` works fine and displays the context menu (`JPopupMenu`) if I right click the `JList`.

But my `JList` often is larger (taller) than needed for its entries (as the JList is expanded to window height).

And the context menu always appears, even if I click on the blank area of the JList.

I want the context-menu (JPopupMenu) to only show up, if the user right-clicks an entry, *not* if the user clicks on the blank space below the last list entry.
The menu options are only applicable to a certain entry, not to the `JList` in its entirety.

[image]

I tried `setComponentPopupMenu` on a custom `ListCellRenderer` instead of on the list but that doesn't show a menu at all.

How could I get an only-on-entry context menu for my JList?

Comment: 1) *"only for entries of JList, not all space of the JList"* See [`List.setVisibleRowCount(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int)). 2) If experiencing problems clicking on entries in a list within a popup menu, those can likely be solved by displaying the list in a `JOptionPane` instead. Note that it has a variant specifically designed for a list of choices, so the `JList` might not even be required. 3) **For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].**

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up Popup Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for the "old" way to display the popup so you can control when to display the menu. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743427/jtable-right-click-popup-menu/16744590#16744590 for a basic example using a JTable. The concept would be the same for a JList.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to get the component renderer (renders the items on the list)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getCellRenderer()

Then fetch the component. Then attach a mouselistener, and upon right click, perform whatever action you want.

**EDIT** - Here's an even better way. I wasn't aware of this solution at the time of creating this answer.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class SOQ_20220416
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
      
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setLocation(200, 400);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      frame.add(createPanelAndList());
      
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }
   
   public static JPanel createPanelAndList()
   {
   
      enum Fruit
      {
      
         APPLE,
         BANANA,
         CHERRY,
         ;
      
      }
   
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      
      JList<Fruit> list = new JList<>(Fruit.values());
      
      panel.add(list);
      
      MouseListener mouseListener = 
         new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                  int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                  System.out.println("Right clicked on Item " + index);
               }
            }
         };
   
      list.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
      
      return panel;
   
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to override `JPopupMenu#show(Component, int, int)` method. Since it is possible to get the coordinates of the click, you can control whether the `JPopupMenu` is shown or hidden by doing `super.show(c, x, y);` only if those coordinates are in a `JList` cell.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListPopupMenuTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    String[] model = {"Entry 1", "Entry 2", "Entry 3"};
    JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
    list.setComponentPopupMenu(new ListPopupMenu());
    return new JScrollPane(list);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ListPopupMenuTest().makeUI());
      frame.setSize(320, 240);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class ListPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {
  protected ListPopupMenu() {
    super();
    add("Item 1").addActionListener(System.out::println);
    add("Item 2").addActionListener(System.out::println);
    addSeparator();
    add("Item 3").addActionListener(System.out::println);
  }

  @Override public void show(Component c, int x, int y) {
    if (c instanceof JList) {
      JList<?> list = (JList<?>) c;
      Point pt = new Point(x, y);
      int idx = list.locationToIndex(pt);
      Rectangle r = list.getCellBounds(idx, idx);
      if (r != null && r.contains(pt)) { // && !list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        super.show(c, x, y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```