# Create a right click popup menu in a text area only if it is not empty and getting the selected index

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextarea, popupmenu

I've seen the question answered in [How do I create a right click context menu in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766956/how-do-i-create-a-right-click-context-menu-in-java-swing)
and seen how I can create a menu.
However, when I associate it with the text area, it doesn't matter if it has anything written on it or not, it always shows the menu.

I use the text area to reveal how many objects I have created from a specific class (which I save in a ArrayList). What I need, is a menu that when clicking on a specific line of text, it can have the index of the object in the ArrayList and use that menu to Edit/Remove that specified object from the ArrayList.
Is that possible with a Text Area or should I use a different type of displaying component?

As an Example:

Text Area:

Object 1.

Object 2.

Object 3.

When I select , for example, Object 1 with a right click, it shows the menu with Edit and Remove. But when I dont select any of them, the menu does not show.
And when it Shows, it can access the index od the object (object 1 -> index 0, object 2 -> index 1 , etc.)

Thanks a lot for your help,
Nhekas

Comment: It's not hard to do. Try it and if you get a problem, then ask us.

Comment: I did try, and what I cannot do is join the location I get from the mouse (MouseEvent.getPoint()) and which line it corresponds in the JTextArea, mostly because, since it is inside a scrollPane, when I scroll down, the getPoint() won't change if I click on the same location.

Comment: Look at JScrollPane's getViewPosition method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use the text area to reveal how many objects I have created from a specific class

Don't use a JTextArea.

Instead I would suggest you should be using a `JList`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples.

The `JList` has a `locationToIndex(...)` method which will give you the row where the mouse was clicked. Then you can get the object from the list.

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks a lot! That makes it easier!