# what is the correct handling of isPopupTrigger() in MouseAdapter

Tags: java, swing, events, menu

I need to write a Java Swing application that will run and act about the same on Linux, Windows and Mac. And for virtually all Widgets I create, I need to add some special handling, including, everything needs to be able to pop up a menu when asked. Even widgets like labels and buttons.

I'm able to catch menu requests by adding:

```
    MouseListener m = new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
          if (e.isPopupTrigger())
          {
            onMenuSummons(); //do my thing
          }
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(m);
```

to the constructor on my extended widget.

But I'm concerned that this is a Linux-only solution. Do I only need to check isPopupEvent() in MousePressed? What about MouseClicked? I could hook both to be sure, but do I run a risk that some platform someday would have isPopupEvent() be true in both functions for the same mouse action?

Ideally MouseAdapter would spare me the question by offering an overridable popupRequest(MouseEvent e), but it doesn't. So what is the always right, works everywhere on all platforms and always will forever solution?

Also, some of the widgets I'm extending may have their own popup menus; I need to suppress those and implement my own. How do I make sure only my own menu is displayed? TIA.

Comment: Yes, generally speaking, the pop up trigger is different on each platform 

Comment: Yes.  You need to check mousePressed, mouseReleased, and mouseClicked.  As for suppressing built-in context menus, you can try calling consume() on the event in your listener method.  That may or may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing up a Popup Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for the basic of using menus and popup menus.

To write a MouseListener the basic code is:

```
class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        maybeShowPopup(e);
    }

    private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
            popup.show(e.getComponent(),
                       e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

> some of the widgets I'm extending may have their own popup menus; I need to suppress those and implement my own.

Also note the the example from the tutorial is older. The newer approach for adding a popup menu to a component is to use:

```
component.setComponentPopupMenu(....);
```

Not sure, but since this method only allows a single popup it may replace the default popup?

Comment: Ok, so that argues that the popup state will be revealed either by Pressed or Released, never both and never Clicked.  That helps.

Is "everybody as Java 11" a reasonably safe assumption? I'm writing code for friends and find plenty of old examples (eg, never heard of setComponentPopupMenu before) but I don't want to use anything that's not commonly available.

Comment: The setComponentPopupMenu() method was added in JDK1.5 I believe.